# Converting object to an encodable object failed

Tags: json, serialization, dart, encode

I am getting the following error:

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Patient'
#0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:674)
#1      _JsonStringifier.writeList (dart:convert/json.dart:724)
#2      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue (dart:convert/json.dart:706)
#3      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:664)
#4      _JsonStringStringifier.printOn (dart:convert/json.dart:873)
#5      _JsonStringStringifier.stringify (dart:convert/json.dart:855)
#6      JsonEncoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:256)
#7      JsonCodec.encode (dart:convert/json.dart:155)
#8      Persistence.saveLatestPatients (/Users/dean/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/570CC18D-95BF-4062-8523-9C78E106D0CF/data/Containers/Data/Application/70CAEFAA-4AE3-4CBF-A85F-39161E472C83/tmp/flutter_prototypev6jYbr/flutter_prototype/lib/utils/persistence.dart:32:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      _HomeScreenState.fetchData.<anonymous closure> (/Users/dean/Librar<…>
```

My 'Patient' class:

```
import 'package:simple_moment/simple_moment.dart';

class Patient {
  String guid;
  String _name;
  String _surname;
  DateTime _updated;

  Patient(String guid) {
    this.guid = guid;
  }

  String get name => _name;
  set name(v) => _name = v;

  String get surname => _surname;
  set surname(v) => _surname = v;

  DateTime get updated => _updated;
  set updated(v) => _updated = v;

  // Helper functions

  String getFullName() => '$_name $_surname';

  String getRelativeLastUpdated() {
    var moment = new Moment.now();
    return moment.from(_updated);
  }

}
```

Comment: In my case I was directly passing Model class object as request param using DIO network library. I just had to convert it to json before making API call.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can't just convert any arbitrary class instance to JSON.

**This due to the fact that Flutter does not support reflection.** Thus, no dart program in a flutter application can determine, which properties a class features. Therefore, no magic can serialize arbitrarily objects in Flutter.

One option is to provide a custom function to the JsonEncoder() constructor (via the `toEncodable` argument). This custom function should map your custom objects to types that JsonEncoder already knows how to handle (i.e. numbers, strings, booleans, null, lists and maps with string keys).

Maybe the [reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) plugin might be of use here.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-convert/JsonEncoder-class.html

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable is a package that generates code for that so that you don't need to write it manually.

See also https://flutter.io/json/

Comment: What about dart programs that have nothing to do with flutter? Can magic serialization take place in non-flutter dart applications?

Comment: If you write a console command in pure Dart, you can use reflection and you can build a serializer using reflection that can (de)serialize arbitrary Dart objects.

Answer (score 127):

You don't need to add any libraries. You just have to implement fromJson and toJson functions in your object.

Example:

```
class LinkItem {
  final String name;
  final String url;

  LinkItem({this.name, this.url});

  LinkItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['n'],
        url = json['u'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'n': name,
      'u': url,
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can call jsonEncode:

```
List<LinkItem> list = await getUserLinks();
list.add(linkItem);    
String json = jsonEncode(list);
```

Result:

```
  [{"n":"Google","u":"https://www.google.com/"},{"n":"Test","u":"https://www.test.com/"},{"n":"etc","u":"etc"}]
```

Comment: This is the best answer, which I have used in my app for state store in app memory. where I need to convert the `List<class model>` as `JSON` without using any 3rd party library and using online inbuilt flutter & dart libraries.

Answer (score 44):

In my case, I was attempting to use an integer key in a map object.
Once I converted it to String, the error was resolved. Good luck.

Comment: Totally was the case, although a dumb one XD

Comment: I was using rxInt Lol !!!

Comment: Wasted so much time just because a nested child object had BigInt variable, changing to string made it work.

Comment: Hi, why are integer keys bad?

Comment: @LavnishChaudhary The JSON specification does not permit integer keys. Only string keys are permitted in JSON.

Answer (score 24):

In my case, I was attempting to add a DateTime directly to the map object. Once I converted it to String, the error was resolved.

Before

```
return {
  'birthDay', instance.birthDay
};
```

Now

```
return {
   'birthDay', instance.birthDay?.toIso8601String(),
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to use an `Uri` into the map of dio request parameter. Converting it to String resolved the issue.

Error in directly using `redirectUrl` an instance of `Uri`

```
data: {
      'client_id': identifier,
      'client_secret': secret,
      'code': code,
      'redirect_uri': redirectUrl
    });
```

No error after converting to `String`.

```
data: {
      'client_id': identifier,
      'client_secret': secret,
      'code': code,
      'redirect_uri': redirectUrl.toString()
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case,

```
return file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(addNewScore(scorer, s)));
```

`jsonEncode` was throwing an error `Converting object to an encodable object failed: _LinkedHashMap len:1`

{ turnoff: { times: { 15: [ {score: 6, ts: 1640916433851}]}}} <-- here 15 was actually `int`

so after converting that property from `int` to `String` able to get correctly

{ "turnoff": { "times": { "15": [{"score":6,"ts":1640916433851}]} } }

**JSON does not allow integer keys or properties**

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have added more than one '{' braces, while forming the json request. After removing the braces, it worked well.

```
jsonEncode({
{
  'isAnonymous': request.isAnonymous,
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

It may cause due to various reasons. So, I have listed all possible scenarios and you can check which one is your problem:

1. You cannot use non-string keys for the map (dictionary). For example:

```
{
  1:value
} //This is wrong as you have used the integer key!
```

2. Using non-encodable formats as a value. For example, you cannot use the $DateTime$ variable in the value and you should make sure you are converting it to a string by calling $.toString()$:

```
{
   "date":my_date.toString()
} // then you should convert it in your fromJson method
```

or Uri object:

```
{
   "url":my_uri.toString()
} // then you should convert it in your fromJson method
```

3. you haven't implemented $toJson$ and $fromJson$ methods. Try to do it as follows:

```
LinkItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : key1= json['key1'],
        key2= json['key2'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'key1': key1,
      'key2': key2,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a method named toJson()  to a class that you need to do the conversion. Put logic of converting in that method and use `this.propety_name` to reference properties. look at the example of a method here
`String toJson() { return jsonEncode({}); }`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was caused by using an enum in the class

```
late final RelationshipStatus _status;
```

Caused an issue:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    '_status': _status,
  };
```

Solution:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    '_status': _status.name
  };
```