# is it possible to store DocumentReference in shared_preferences in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

while I'm trying to store DocumentReference type I'm getting this below error

Unhandled Exception: Converting an object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DocumentReference'

I'm thinking the parse error but I don't know exactly

Comment: Please share the few piece of code where you are getting exception and the complete stacktrace

Comment: JSON OBJECT ------> {subTotal: 14999.0, grandTotal: 14999.0, deliveryCharge: 0.0, deliveryLocation: null, products: [{quantity: 1, productRef: DocumentReference(products/5RVVNBMXxiYqJ0lTrfYX)}], userRef: DocumentReference(users/2rdRXf2on6h0B3igNvwn0IIOWox1), createdAt: 2020-10-24 21:15:25.083351, paymentType: null, tax: 0.0}

store to sharedPreference method ------------>
static Future<bool> setCartInfo(Map<String, dynamic> cartInfo) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setString('cartInfo', jsonEncode(cartInfo));
  }

Comment: Below line is the error
Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DocumentReference'

Answer (score 1):

By document reference do you mean the data that you get from the document reference?

The data in the shared preference is stored in key value pair. The value cannot be an object, it has to be either `int`, `string` or `bool` etc. So, you'll first need to convert value stored in the class to a json string. Also, note that not all objects can be converted to json. For your particular error look:
Look: [Converting object to an encodable object failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753412/converting-object-to-an-encodable-object-failed)

That being said, the thing you can do is first get the data from the document reference and then store it on the `shared_pref`, rather than trying to store the document_reference itself.

You could also get the id of the document and then store that particular document path as the key and the data as the value, incase you need to access that particular document.

Comment: I need to store the DocumentReference type of data