# Converting object to an encodable object fails on first run

Tags: json, flutter, encoding

Does it make any sense that I get this error when I save a list of objects for the first time only? when I add another object to the list, the same code runs without errors. Is there a little trick that I'm missing?

> E/flutter ( 6026): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]
> Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed:
> Instance of 'Proje' E/flutter ( 6026): #0
> _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:688:7) E/flutter ( 6026): #1      _JsonStringifier.writeList
> (dart:convert/json.dart:736:7) E/flutter ( 6026): #2
> _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue (dart:convert/json.dart:718:7) E/flutter ( 6026): #3      _JsonStringifier.writeObject
> (dart:convert/json.dart:679:9) E/flutter ( 6026): #4
> _JsonStringifier.writeMap (dart:convert/json.dart:769:7) E/flutter ( 6026): #5      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue
> (dart:convert/json.dart:724:21) E/flutter ( 6026): #6
> _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:679:9) E/flutter ( 6026): #7      _JsonStringStringifier.printOn
> (dart:convert/json.dart:877:17) E/flutter ( 6026): #8
> _JsonStringStringifier.stringify (dart:convert/json.dart:862:5) E/flutter ( 6026): #9      JsonEncoder.convert
> (dart:convert/json.dart:262:30) E/flutter ( 6026): #10
> JsonCodec.encode (dart:convert/json.dart:172:45) E/flutter ( 6026):
> #11     StorageImpl.flush (package:get_storage/src/storage/io.dart:34:37) E/flutter ( 6026): #12
> GetStorage._flush (package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart:144:23)
> E/flutter ( 6026): #13     GetQueue._check
> (package:get/get_utils/src/queue/get_queue.dart:31:47) E/flutter (
> 6026): #14     GetQueue.add
> (package:get/get_utils/src/queue/get_queue.dart:43:5) E/flutter (
> 6026): #15     GetStorage._addToQueue
> (package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart:139:18) E/flutter ( 6026):
> #16     Microtask.exec. (package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart:174:17) E/flutter ( 6026):
> #17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47) E/flutter ( 6026): #18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19) E/flutter ( 6026): #19     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7) E/flutter ( 6026): #20     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23) E/flutter ( 6026): #21     _rootRun
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13) E/flutter ( 6026): #22
> _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19) E/flutter ( 6026): #23     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7) E/flutter ( 6026): #24     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23) E/flutter ( 6026): #25
> _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21) E/flutter ( 6026): #26     _startMicrotaskLoop
> (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)

and here is the class file:

```
class Proje {
  int id;
  String title;
  int tahminiButce;

  Proje({this.id, this.title, this.tahminiButce});

  factory Proje.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Proje(
      id: int.parse(json["id"]),
      title: json["title"],
      tahminiButce: int.parse(json["tahminiButce"]),
    );
  }
//

}
```

and here is the code that runs to save the list:

```
void saveOrUpdate() {
      var pb = int.tryParse(tec2.text);
      var _id = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      if (index == null) {
        curP.title = tec.text;
        curP.tahminiButce = pb == null ? 0 : pb;
        curP.id = _id;
        pc.projeList.add(curP);
      } else {
        curP = pc.projeList[index];
        curP.title = tec.text;
        curP.tahminiButce = pb == null ? 0 : int.parse(tec2.text);
        pc.projeList[index] = curP;
      }
      Get.back();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/49753478/10659482

Comment: So is it OK that it works the second time without errors?

Comment: No, it is not ok. Try this:

 factory Proje.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Proje(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
        tahminiButce: json["tahminiButce"] == null ? null : json["tahminiButce"],
    );

Comment: Still the same, error on the first run, no error after that.

Comment: With this limited info, I don't have an idea. But we can look deeply. Connect me via https://www.linkedin.com/in/deremakif/