# Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Error:

```
Произошло исключение.
JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Closure: () => Map<dynamic, dynamic>)
```

Code:

```
Map toJson() => {
                "UnigTime": {
                  "hour": _timerHourCurrentSliderValue,
                  "minute": _timerMinuteCurrentSliderValue.toInt()
                }
              };
          final jsonAllTime = jsonEncode(toJson);
          Server().async(jsonAllTime);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753412/converting-object-to-an-encodable-object-failed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to convert a `Function`. instead of this line

```
          final jsonAllTime = jsonEncode(toJson);
```

you should have this line where it returns the `Map`

```dart
          final jsonAllTime = jsonEncode(toJson());
```