# How can i convert my Map with custom data types to Json

Tags: json, dart

Firstly i have a Class named Event in this class i storage only 1 string variable. I have a Map variable which i storage DateTime and List<Event> while i am  converting this map to json i am getting an error.

And I feel like i will get an error while converting json to map if u have knowladge please explane how can i make it work i am very new at dart

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: _LinkedHashMap len:1

```
class Event{
  final String title;
  Event({required this.title});

  String toString() => this.title;
}
// under this, codes are inside of widget
Map<DateTime, List<Event>>? selectedEvents; // this variable have some data its not an issue

print(json.encode(selectedEvents)); // error
```

i tried to follow this [question]([Converting object to an encodable object failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753412/converting-object-to-an-encodable-object-failed)) but it was so complex for me to get it

Answer (score 0):

those are worked

```
    class Event{
  final String title;
  Event({required this.title});

  String toString() => this.title;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {'title': title};
  }


  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Event(title: json['title']);
  }

}
  Map<String, dynamic> encodeSelectedEvents(Map<DateTime, List<Event>> selectedEvents) {
    Map<String, dynamic> encodedEvents = {};
    selectedEvents.forEach((key, value) {
      encodedEvents[key.toString()] = value.map((event) => event.toJson()).toList();
    });
    return encodedEvents;
  }

  Map<DateTime, List<Event>> decodeSelectedEvents(String jsonString) {
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedEvents = json.decode(jsonString);
    Map<DateTime, List<Event>> selectedEvents = {};
    decodedEvents.forEach((key, value) {
      selectedEvents[DateTime.parse(key)] = value.map((event) => Event.fromJson(event)).toList();
    });
    return selectedEvents;
  }
```