# Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'SharedString'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Was trying to convert `Map` to `JSON` using `josnEncode()` but it threw

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'SharedString'
#0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:793:7)
#1      _JsonStringifier.writeMap (dart:convert/json.dart:874:7)
#2      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue (dart:convert/json.dart:829:21)
#3      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:784:9)
#4      _JsonStringStringifier.printOn (dart:convert/json.dart:982:17)
#5      _JsonStringStringifier.stringify (dart:convert/json.dart:967:5)
#6      JsonEncoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:345:30)
#7      JsonCodec.encode (dart:convert/json.dart:232:37)

                             excel_to_json_converter.dart:39
<asynchronous suspension>
```

my code:

```
 String data = jsonEncode(
    finalArJson,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find it here better. Please check this!

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753412/converting-object-to-an-encodable-object-failed][1]

You should ensure that all objects within "finalArJson" are instances of classes that implement the toJson method or are of types natively supported by JSON encoding (e.g., int, double, String, List, Map).

Example

```
void main() {
  List<CustomObject> finalArJson = [
    CustomObject('value1', 42),
    CustomObject('value2', 99),
    // Add more CustomObject instances or other supported types
  ];

  // Convert List<CustomObject> to List<Map<String, dynamic>>
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonList = finalArJson.map((obj) => obj.toJson()).toList();

  // Convert the entire list to a JSON-formatted string
  String data = jsonEncode(jsonList);

  print(data);
}
```

Your Custom Object

```
class CustomObject {
  String property1;
  int property2;

  CustomObject(this.property1, this.property2);

  // Implement the toJson method for custom objects
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'property1': property1,
      'property2': property2,
    };
  }
}
```

Output

```
[
  {"property1": "value1", "property2": 42},
  {"property1": "value2", "property2": 99}
]
```

Hope you will find it helpful. Thanks