# Flutter - Converting object to an encodable object failed

Tags: flutter, dart, type-conversion

E/flutter ( 8110): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Color'

I keep getting this error

```
          String colorToHex(Color color) {
        return '#${color.value.toRadixString(16)}';
      }
          ///
      void setFontColor(Color newColor) async {
        _fontColor = newColor;

        // Convert the Color object to a hex color string
        String hexColor = colorToHex(newColor);

        await _prefs.setString('fontColor', hexColor);
        notifyListeners();
      }

        Color _getFontColorFromString(SharedPreferences prefs) {
      String fontColorString =
          prefs.getString('fontColor') ?? AppConstants.fontColorHex;

      // Remove any '#' symbol if present
      fontColorString = fontColorString.replaceAll('#', '');

      // Check if the string length is 6 (without alpha) or 8 (with alpha)
      if (fontColorString.length == 6 || fontColorString.length == 8) {
        // Add 'FF' as alpha if it's not present
        if (fontColorString.length == 6) {
          fontColorString = 'FF' + fontColorString;
        }

        // Parse the hex color string
        Color fontColor = Color(int.parse(fontColorString, radix: 16));
        return fontColor;
      } //
      else {
        // Handle the case where the format is invalid

        return Color(
            int.parse(AppConstants.fontColorHex.replaceAll('0x', ''), radix: 16));
      }
    }
```

Some other method:

```
                        // Retrieve user preferences

                    Color fontColor = _getFontColorFromString(preferences);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting object to an encodable object failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753412/converting-object-to-an-encodable-object-failed)

Comment: I went through it before posting this question. I don't know how it works in my case.

Comment: Which part of the code causing the error?

Comment: I don't know, it says unhandled exception. I have try catch almost everywhere. But it's either the setting part or the getting part, only these 2 functions are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of  colorToHex Function will solve the problem

```
String colorToHex(Color color) {
  return '#${color.value.toRadixString(16).padLeft(8, '0')}';
}
```

Comment: I already have that function. I have edited the code, it's at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store color as integer value representing its ARGB format and at time of retrieval again convert to Color object.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ColorStorage {
  final SharedPreferences _prefs;

  ColorStorage(this._prefs);

  // Save color to shared preferences
  Future<void> saveColor(Color color) async {
    // Convert color to ARGB integer
    int colorValue = color.value;
    await _prefs.setInt('color', colorValue);
  }

  Color getColor() {
    int? colorValue = _prefs.getInt('color');
    if (colorValue == null) {
      return Colors.black;
    }
    return Color(colorValue); // Convert integer color value to Color object
  }
}

// Example usage:
void main() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  ColorStorage colorStorage = ColorStorage(prefs);

  // Save color
  Color colorToSave = Colors.blue;
  await colorStorage.saveColor(colorToSave);

  // Retrieve color
  Color retrievedColor = colorStorage.getColor();
  print(retrievedColor); // Output: Color(0xFF0000FF)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save the shared preference as Int?

Unless you want to show the Color hex somewhere you can just save the value into the shared preference as an Int.

```dart
void setFontColor(Color newColor) async {
    _fontColor = newColor;

    await _prefs.setInt('fontColor', newColor.value);

    notifyListeners();
}

Color _getFontColorFromString(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    // Replace your AppConstants.fontColorHex to the color value
    int fontColor = prefs.getInt('fontColor') ?? AppConstants.fontColorHex;

    return Color(fontColor);      
}
```

There is no need to convert the string to radix for storing and using it. You can use the colorToHex function for displaying the hex.